# NullPointerException trying to send e-mail with OAuth in Android

Tags: android, smtp, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to send an e-mail using Google's Gmail API and OAuth 2.0. I manage to get what appears to be a valid SMTPTransport (not entirely sure it's valid), but when I go to try and send an e-mail I get a NullPointerException on the line where sendMessage occurs. Actually, the exception doesn't happen exactly on that line. What is weird is that in Eclipse the current line in the debugger goes back to the first line in the sendMail method and then returns to the calling client with a NullPointerException. I can't tell what is causing the null exception. The smtpTransport and msg variables are not null:

```
  private Session session;

  public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail, String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
      session = Session.getInstance(props);
      session.setDebug(debug);

      final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
      SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);

      // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
      final String emptyPassword = null;
      transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

      byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
      response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

      transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

      return transport;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user, String oauthToken, String recipients)
  {
    try
    {
      SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587, user, oauthToken, true);

      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
      DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
      message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
      message.setSubject(subject);
      message.setDataHandler(handler);

      if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
      else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

      smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**
I updated the code in sendMail but still have the same problem. The logcat shows no exceptions at all. In fact, the connection to the server is accepted. However, if I run the code a number of times, I eventually do get an exception in logcat as follows:

> Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from
>   method myapp.sendMail

Not sure why it can't find DataHandler. Potentially something missing a jar file that doesn't get detected during compile time but only at runtime?

```
02-28 14:33:14.619: I/ActivityManager(199): Starting: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras) } from pid 967
02-28 14:33:14.619: E/ActivityManager(199): exception bw.write()java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected
02-28 14:33:14.619: D/PowerManagerService(199): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
02-28 14:33:14.899: E/ActivityRecord(199): sendActivityPerformanceInfo exception occurs: java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected
02-28 14:33:14.899: I/ActivityManager(199): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +260ms
02-28 14:33:14.909: D/PowerManagerService(199): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
02-28 14:33:16.879: E/ActivityManager(199): exception bw.write()java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected
02-28 14:33:16.879: D/PowerManagerService(199): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
02-28 14:33:17.089: I/ActivityManager(199): Process com.google.android.gms (pid 642) has died.
02-28 14:33:18.629: D/PowerManagerService(199): acquireWakeLock flags=0xa tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG
02-28 14:33:18.649: W/InputManagerService(199): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40928628 (uid=10025 pid=1085)
02-28 14:33:18.719: D/PowerManagerService(199): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
02-28 14:33:22.139: D/PowerManagerService(199): releaseWakeLock flags=0xa tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG
02-28 14:33:23.969: I/System.out(967): DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.6
02-28 14:33:23.989: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
02-28 14:33:24.009: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
02-28 14:33:24.139: I/System.out(967): 220 mx.google.com ESMTP 44sm11905543eek.5 - gsmtp
02-28 14:33:24.139: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
02-28 14:33:24.149: I/System.out(967): EHLO localhost
02-28 14:33:24.219: I/System.out(967): 250-mx.google.com at your service, [217.238.138.215]
02-28 14:33:24.239: I/System.out(967): 250-SIZE 35882577
02-28 14:33:24.239: I/System.out(967): 250-8BITMIME
02-28 14:33:24.239: I/System.out(967): 250-STARTTLS
02-28 14:33:24.259: I/System.out(967): 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
02-28 14:33:24.269: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
02-28 14:33:24.269: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
02-28 14:33:24.269: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
02-28 14:33:24.279: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
02-28 14:33:24.289: I/System.out(967): STARTTLS
02-28 14:33:24.359: I/System.out(967): 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
02-28 14:33:25.319: I/System.out(967): EHLO localhost
02-28 14:33:25.589: I/System.out(967): 250-mx.google.com at your service, [217.238.138.215]
02-28 14:33:25.599: I/System.out(967): 250-SIZE 35882577
02-28 14:33:25.609: I/System.out(967): 250-8BITMIME
02-28 14:33:25.609: I/System.out(967): 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2
02-28 14:33:25.619: I/System.out(967): 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
02-28 14:33:25.629: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
02-28 14:33:25.639: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
02-28 14:33:25.639: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2"
02-28 14:33:25.639: I/System.out(967): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
02-28 14:33:25.679: I/System.out(967): AUTH XOAUTH2 ??????????????????????????????==
02-28 14:33:26.309: I/System.out(967): 235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

Comment: I added it as well as updated the code in the sendMail method. Nothing shows up in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is incompatibility with jar files used for mail stuff. The jar files needed for Android can be downloaded at:

https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list